# Flip left and right animation is not working in ionic 2

Tags: animation, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working with ionic 2 application and facing the issue of flip animation.

I want to put a flip animation on ion-col (flip left and flip right), but the flip animation is not working sometimes.

I am referring the flip animation from below link-

Reference link - https://www.joshmorony.com/using-the-web-animations-api-in-ionic-2/

.html code

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col [@flip]="flipState" col-6
                 (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)">

        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

.ts code

Set the animation first

```
animations: [

    trigger('flip', [
        state('flipped', style({
            transform: 'rotateY(360deg)',
        })),
        transition('* => flipped', animate('500ms ease'))
    ]),

]
```

})

when swipeEvent method called

```
swipeEvent(ev) {
 if ((ev.direction === 2 || ev.direction === 4)) {
         this.flipState = 'flipped';
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one off of GitHub.  This is the one I used as starting point

https://github.com/JesseSoldat/Flip-Card-Ionic-2.git

Comment: I appreciate your answer and help but my requirement is different.
When I debug, I found that the flip animation is not working for the first 2 times after that the animation is working properly.

I don't know what's wrong, please help.